# Algorithm help find "outliers" in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, finite-fields

I have vectors $v_i$ such that $1\leq i \leq m $ of dimension $n$ where $m > n$. Members of the vectors $v$ belongs to $GF(2^k)$ (hope it makes it easier).

Ideally, all these vectors should be in the same vectorspace formed by any $n$ of these vectors. But in my problem there are few vectors that doesn't belong to the vector space.

$m$ and $n$ are usually in the range of 40 and 20 which results in a big combination of $n$ elements out of $m$ that I think isn't practical to traverse all of these combinations !!

Comment: If you choose $n$ of these vectors and they are linearly independent, then all other vectors belong the the vector space formed by these $n$ vectors.

Comment: i707107 The problem is choosing these n vectors from the m vectors. I need something efficient. I know a way that might work for real numbers but it won't work for finite fields.

Comment: Have you any rough estimate of the number of outliers, if any? It may make quite a difference for some simple non-deterministic approach, if we are reasonable sure that, for example, at most two vectors out of 40 are outside the subspace spanned by the others. Of course, if you want an algorithm that works with 100 per cent certainty then that may not help :-/

Comment: And, it is difficult to see what kind of an approach would work for reals but fail over a field where there are no approximation errors to cater for. Can you describe your idea for the reals?

Comment: My idea, I imagined it with two dimension vectors. It basically worked because reals abide by Euclidean measures. I didn't try it though in my example with higher number of dimensions, I am not sure how I will make it work for that case and I didn't make an effort for that case anyway because reals aren't what I should represent my codes in.